# Selenium (Java) how to find an element from a list of possible elements

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, element

new to selenium, to simplify it, there are 50 possible elements that can appear on a page, so I have those 50 driver.findElement(By.xpath().click(), to click on any of the elements that may appear, my problem is, is that if a findelement is flase the program ends, but what I want is to check the first element, if its false, check the second, if the second is false, check the third until it finds the findelement that is true and click on it. What would be the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: How would you define that false/true as a result of `findelement()`? It's a bit unclear what is the condition behind skipping or clicking an element.

Answer (score 0):

How different are the elements? That will help produce a better answer but the answer to the second part of the question... how do you check for an element and then proceed if not found, I would do something like this.

Build a `List<>` of your locators (the By.* stuff), loop through them looking for one that matches, if you find a match then click it.

```
List<By> locators = new ArrayList<>();
locators.add(By.id("someId"));
locators.add(By.cssSelector("div.someClass"));
// add all your locators to the List<>

for (By locator : locators)
{
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(locator);
    if (elements.size() > 0)
    {
        elements.get(0).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: they are all very similar they all look like this -   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@title='TITILEHERE!']")).click();

Comment: Do you want to find elements with a specific img title or elements in a certain location on the page or ?

Answer (score -1):

Make an array of xpaths and then loop through them until you get a hit on an element.